# What's the complement to minutiae?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm trying to describe a high level job thus

> You have to worry about the minutiae and the ...

I'm looking for a word that is the opposite of small details... i.e. the big picture.

Is there a word that means that but that remains as close to the Latin root as minutiae?

Comment: If you want to keep Latin, _totius_ springs to mind.

Comment: OK, OK, I confess. I used Google.

Comment: ***Macro***? ***Material*** (as in relevant, germane things, in contrast to irrelevant detail)?

Comment: I would suggest *the macro perspective," since "macro" looks close to "magnum."

Comment: It is because minutiae is fancy that I would never pair it with more fanciness, but with _the big sweep_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several words of Latin origin that can be used. Here are a few:

**Totality** is from the Medieval Latin *[totalitas](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=totality&allowed_in_frame=0)* and Latin *[totus](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=total&allowed_in_frame=0)*, meaning all, all at once, entire, altogether. (Etymonline.com)

**Entirety** is from Latin *[integritatem](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=entirety&allowed_in_frame=0)*, meaning completeness, soundness, integrity. (Etymonline.com)

**Aggregation** is from Latin *[ad-](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=ad-&allowed_in_frame=0)* meaning with regard to and *[gregarius](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=gregarious&allowed_in_frame=0)* meaning pertaining to the flock or the herd (as opposed to the individuals within it). (Etymonline.com)

Comment: In AmE, though, "overview" might be the word used in the workplace.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps also:
**Comprehension**
from Latin comprehensiō (“taking together”), from com- (“with, together”) +‎ prehendō (“take”) [wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/comprehension) in the sense of all encompassing considerations,

or in a more colloquial vernacular:

**Comprehensives**  as used for example, when speaking of PhD qualifying exams.

The added import of the **comprehend** root is of course understanding which is implied in the sense of **minutiae** as used above.